# How to force newlines in comments?

Tags: support, comment, markdown, formatting

When I write a comment, I don't know how to go to the next line because if I press Enter button It will submit the comment.

Comment: No, $$\quad$$ it's $$\quad$$ not $$\quad$$ possible. :)

Comment: @Daniel,$\tag*{}$Also using subtler methods.$\tag*{}$--- Asaf.

Comment: There are several older discussions, for example:
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856/linebreaks-in-comments-dont-seem-to-be-working,
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/how-to-do-new-line-in-comments,
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/allow-newline-in-comments

Comment: For long comments, I always use the answer box to edit it first and then copy and paste it to the comment box when it is ready.

Comment: As I mentioned in an old thread, one can use $ $ \tag*{} $ $ in MathJax to force a newline in comments.

Comment: Thanks for you answers.
$\tag*{}$ Why so many thumbs down?

Comment: @Shabbeh: I did not downvote, but the downvotes are probably along the lines of Mad Scientist's answer. I also expressed the same sentiment in [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16489/mathjax-cancel-not-working/16490#comment60393_16490).

Comment: Related: [Linebreaks in comments don't seem to be working](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856/linebreaks-in-comments-dont-seem-to-be-working)

Comment: TEST: $\tag*{Success}$

Answer (score 6):

There is no next line in comments, comments are meant to be short and line breaks are intentionally not allowed.

Comment: I agree with you but sometimes it gets too messy especially when you are using LaTeX.

Comment: @Shabbeh If you only want a new line while editing,

so that you can better proof-read what you're writing, and don't insist on it being rendered, then you can type Shift+Return, that places the cursor on the next line, and does not submit.

Comment: @Shabbeh: with any LaTeX, if things become too crowded or confusing in `\textstyle`, formulas can be set in `\displaystyle`. Just use `$$...$$`

Comment: My general rule of thumb: if you want a "new line" to separate paragraphs, you should probably start a new comment.

Answer (score 1):

Promoting information in the comments to an answer for visibility.

Shift+Enter will move to the next line in the edit window, but this will not render as a newline in the output (it renders as a space).

To force newlines in the output we can use MathJax. By quoting Asaf's comment above in a Chatroom, you can see [how the sausage is made](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61684078#61684078):

```
@Daniel,$\tag*{}$Also using subtler methods.$\tag*{}$--- Asaf.
```

If you can't remember to use `$\tag*$`, you might also remember that the code `$$...$$` also starts on a new line, so an essentially empty version of this also makes a newline. This is how Daniel R's comment works (see [this chatroom message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61684083#61684083)):

```
No, $$\quad$$ it's $$\quad$$ not $$\quad$$ possible. :)
```

Comment: $\text{You can also use \\\\ and \\text\{\}}\\ \text{inside MathJax}$

Comment: Thanks for a great workaround, however, the recipe \tag*{}  skips a line before starting a new line. How can one make the effect of a new paragraph in the comment, without skipping a line?

Comment: @mathreader unfortunately these are hacks so I wouldn't expect too much. But did you see the comment above yours? if you right click > Show Math As > TeX Commands a pop up should appear giving the source which is `\text{You can also use \\\\ and \\text\{\}}\\ \text{inside MathJax}` (you can put that between `$...$`.)

Comment: Wow, thanks! I did not notice that your very first comment actually implements that effect! Let me try this: $\\ \text{This}\\ \text{is}\\ \text{working}\\ \text{but}\\ \text{weirdly}$. Any ideas how to make it start at the very beginning of the line?

Comment: @mathreader $\tag*{}$ $\text{no,}\\ \text{unless you do it all in MathJax anyway. Doesn't feel right though}$

Comment: $\text{Let me try it again...}\\ 
\text{Now I am happy!}\\
\text{Thanks a lot!}$